# TCP vs UDP throughput

Tags: tcp, udp

Suppose we have tcp and udp connection over the same link of capacity C . Tcp has transfer rate of C whereas UDP has 8C as its transfer rate . Which will be more efficient ?

Comment: yes it is assignment. But with given data am not able to arrive at solution.

Comment: This seems like flawed reasoning. In a general sense, UDP is only thinner because it's missing any sort of safety, which you'll add if you want to preserve data integrity (games don't count, where you can just drop packets and still function).

Comment: the capacity and transfer rate are missing a unit. if you consider they have the same unit (e.g. kb/s), then how can you have a connection using 8 times the capacity of the link ? it seems some informations are missing from the text of the assignment...

Comment: there is an option "can't say anything" I am going with that.

Comment: Apparently the U in UDP stands for Unicorn. How else can your transfer rate by 8x the link capacity?

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically, if nothing on the way happens to any of the packets, UDP would be faster. UDP doesn't require to acknowledge every packet like TCP does (ACK Flag). Also, no handshake and no connection tear-down is required. UDP would be the faster choice in an ideal network, where no packets get dropped.

The problem is, in a real world example, UDP would lose packets. You would be slower, because you would have to implement a packet control like in TCP in UDP too. UDP does not acknowledge the receival of packets, and it also does not *knock* on the door to see if anybody is home (TCP SYN). UDP Packets are easier structured than TCP packets, but sacrifice security for their size. http://www.diffen.com/difference/TCP_vs_UDP describes the differences.

So for your example. With a cable that can hold C packets/s, and TCP at a rate of C packets/s and UDP at a rate of 8*C packets/s, UDP would be much faster.

Comment: TCP does not have to acknowledge every packet.